# failed to deserialize solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction: io error: failed to fill whole buffer

Tags: solana-sdk

I am using C++to interact with Solana. Specifically, the Jsonrpc: HTTP method is used. When I created a transaction (an old-fashioned Solana transaction), packaged the transaction information and signed it, and sent the transaction to the Solana testing website, I received this error. Did I type the wrong bag?

Comment: Please provide some more information with the exact code that you used. It looks like the transaction wasn't created properly